# Multivariable Linear Regression using tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, linear-regression

I reused TensorFlow code for multivariable linear regression and tried to reduce the cost but the problem is that after some iterations, the cost as well as the values of W and b becomes inf and quickly nan. Can someone please tell me where the problem is.
I have about 100,000 values. I have trimmed it to 10,000 values for testing.
The dataset is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-8Ww7Zk5fxJT0kwVFI3OUZCcjg/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf



def computeX():

    all_xs = np.loadtxt("test.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=range(4,260)) #reads the columns except first one 


    timestamps = np.loadtxt("test.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=(0),dtype =str)
    symbols = np.loadtxt("test.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=(1),dtype =float)
    categories = np.loadtxt("test.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=(2),dtype =str)

    tempList = []
    BOW = {"M1": 1.0, "M5": 2.0, "M15": 3.0, "M30": 4.0, "H1": 5.0, "H4": 6.0, "D1": 7.0}

    #explode dates and make them features.. 2016/11/1 01:54 becomes [2016, 11, 1, 01, 54]
    for i, v in enumerate(timestamps):
        splitted = v.split()
        dateVal = splitted[0]
        timeVal = splitted[1]
        ar = dateVal.split("/")
        splittedTime = timeVal.split(":")

        ar = ar + splittedTime

        Features = np.asarray(ar)
        Features = Features.astype(float)

        # append symbols

        Features = np.append(Features,symbols[i])

        #append categories from BOW

        Features = np.append(Features, BOW[categories[i]] )
        row = np.append(Features,all_xs[i])
        row = row.tolist()
        tempList.append(row)

    all_xs = np.array(tempList)
    del tempList[:]
    return all_xs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("Starting....")


    learn_rate = 0.5

    all_ys = np.loadtxt("test.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=3) 
#reads only first column  

    all_xs = computeX()

    datapoint_size= int(all_xs.shape[0])

    print(datapoint_size)
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 263], name="x")
    W = tf.Variable(tf.ones([263,1]), name="W")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1]), name="b")

    product = tf.matmul(x,W)
    y = product + b

    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [datapoint_size])

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_-y))/ (2*datapoint_size)

    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learn_rate).minimize(cost)

    sess = tf.Session()


    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    batch_size = 10000
    steps =10
    for i in range(steps):
      print("Entering Loop")
      if datapoint_size == batch_size:
         batch_start_idx = 0
      elif datapoint_size < batch_size:
         raise ValueError("datapoint_size: %d, must be greater than batch_size: %d" % (datapoint_size, batch_size))
      else:
         batch_start_idx = (i * batch_size) % (datapoint_size - batch_size)
      batch_end_idx = batch_start_idx + batch_size
      batch_xs = all_xs[batch_start_idx:batch_end_idx]
      batch_ys = all_ys[batch_start_idx:batch_end_idx]
      xs = np.array(batch_xs)
      ys = np.array(batch_ys)

      feed = { x: xs, y_: ys }

      sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=feed)  
      print("W: %s" % sess.run(W))
      print("b: %f" % sess.run(b))
      print("cost: %f" % sess.run(cost, feed_dict=feed))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your data:

```
id8         id9         id10    id11    id12
1451865600  1451865600  -19.8   87.1    0.5701
1451865600  1451865600  -1.6    3.6     0.57192
1451865600  1451865600  -5.3    23.9    0.57155
```

You also initialize your weights to one, if you multiply all you input data with one, and add them up, all the 'heavy' columns (id8, id9, etc, columns with large numbers) will push away the data from the smaller columns). Also you have columns which are filled with zeros:

```
id236   id237   id238   id239   id240
0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0
```

These are all thing which do not play nice together. The large values will result in very high predictions, these will cause the loss to explode and to overflow. Even scaling your learning rate down by a factor of a billion does barely have any effect.

Hence suggestions:

- Inspect your data, get rid of all nonsense data (columns filled with zeros)
- Normalize your input data
- Examine at that point the magnitude or the loss function and then try playing with the learning rate.